# How to handle static assets with webpack server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to create an universal react app (using webpack both on server and on the client) and struggle with images import. I want to write this :

```
import someImage from './someImage.png'

const SomeImage = () => <img src={someImage}/>
```

Here's my webpack config file:

```
var path              = require('path');
var webpack           = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry:  [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './client',
    'babel-polyfill'
  ],
  output: {
    path:     path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'shared'],
    extensions:         ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test:    /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'file?emitFile=false',
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css', { allChunks: true }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
      '*': 'http://127.0.0.1:' + (process.env.PORT || 3000)
    },
    host: '127.0.0.1'
  }
};
```

Obviously it's not working server side because `node` try to read the content of the `./someImage.png` file, resulting in an error.

How can I handle this ? I know there are packages such as [`webpack-isomorphic-tools`](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools) or [`universal-webpack`](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/universal-webpack) or even the file-loader package that can emit or not the file, but I don't understand of to use it in my universal app.

Comment: Why are you importing/inlining the images to begin with? Keep the out if I were you for your sanity.

Comment: Because it's very handy to import assets in my components. That keep the whole things encapsulated and more modular. But maybe there is a better option ?

Comment: @Pcriulan did you find a solution for your problem? If so please share!

Comment: Hi, @Pcriulan, Did you find the solution i'm also getting the same issue. I also tried using file-loader, but its not working. Also with webpack-isomorphic-tools, its giving me 'assets not found' error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using file-loader with emitFile: false to exclude assets from bundling on server side. Works as expected.

```
const imageRules = (emit = true) => ({
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpeg|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
    type: "asset",
    generator: {
        emit: emit,
    },
});
```

Then use it in webpack client config:

```
module: {
    rules: [imageRules()],
},
```

And in server config

```
module: {
    rules: [imageRules(false)],
},
```